# How KML Linestring method works

Tags: kml

How is a Linestring created? I mean, are the points connected one after another or is there an interpolation or other specific method that connects them?

Comment: Do you mean how Google Earth interprets the lineString KML geometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of interpolation used for the kml:LineString element depends on the values of the *kml:altitudeMode* and *kml:tessellate* elements. If the *kml:altitudeMode* value is not *clampToGround* (i.e., absolute or relativeToGround) then the interpolation between two consecutive points is a straight line segment in the 3D WGS 84 geocentric coordinate reference system. For long distances this can go through the surface of the earth.

If *kml:altitudeMode* is *clampToGround* then each point is first projected to the terrain surface along a line through the earth's center of mass, then interpolated between the
projected control points along a straight line segment in the 3D WGS 84 geocentric coordinate reference system as shown in figure below.

[image: Line Segment Interpolated having clamped to ground with tessellate enabled]

Details on interpolation can be found in the KML 2.2 OGC specification (OGC 07-147r2). See section 6.3.2.